# Draw/ Annoting PDF in xamarin forms

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, annotations

I would like to add some annotations to PDF. Is there any way without using any third party to draw something on pdf? Also should be able to zoom in around 200-500% and draw something and save that pdf as PDF or Png image

Comment: Without third party it could be a lot of work. Believe me I tried by placing annotations through AbsoluteLayout and used Scale and Translate to move them around. There are a lot of things to consider (PDF size, rendered layout size, scrolling, zooming). And hell a lot of code :|. I suggest you to try SfPDFViewer they support annotations. I'm not sure of saving as png Image though. If you find another way please do post it here. Could be of great use to me.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar Thanks alot. I tried converting the PDF into bitmap but the bitmap size is too large that android is not able to display the image. Is there any way to show such large bitmap images without compressing?

Comment: Android does not handle bitmaps well. You have to handle them. Try recycling and scaling down. Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) regarding these. hope it helps.

Comment: Scaling reduces image qualing which won't work in my situation as i have to zoom in around 200-500% and draw which is not even clearly visible when its zoomed out to normal which is why i need to use orginal size image @Nikhileshwar